# Suppressing tensor indices and function labels of a function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am trying to do some GR calculations, and want to write a code which shows the expressions symbolically using compact indices, rather than write all the quantities in detail. More precisely, consider the coordinates $X$, metric $h_{ij}(X)$ and it's conjugate momenta $\Pi_{ij}(X)$ defined using the following code:

```
dim = 4;
coord = Array[X, dim, 0];
HL2 = Table[Subscript[h, i, j][coord], {i, 1, dim - 1}, {j, 1, dim -1}]; 
PL = Table[Subscript[\[Pi], i, j][coord], {i, 1, dim - 1}, {j, 1, dim - 1}];
```

Once I define this, all subsequent expressions are expanded in terms of all the coordinates. e.g. Suppose I want to evaluate $\partial_2 H_m$, where
$$H_m \equiv H_m\, (h_{ij}(X), \, \Pi_{ij}(X)).$$
Naively inserting the following code leads to a huge unwieldy expression:

```
D[ Hm [Flatten[HL2], Flatten[PL]] , coord[[3]]]
```

Is there a way I can utilize the Einstein summation, i.e. keep indices $i,j$ here instead of the complete evaluation? Further, how do I drop off `[{X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3]}]` labels in the output for the metric `Subscript[h, 1, 2][{X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3]}]`. In other words, can I nicely represent the metric as just $h_{ij}$ in the output, while retaining it's properties as a standard function?

Comment: `Hm` isn't defined!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann For now, I don't want to assign a value to `Hm`, and keep it as a general function.

Comment: The chance to get helpful  answers might increase dramatically if you provide a minimal working example!